# E-Mail to Twilio SMS phone number - what would the gateway be?

Tags: twilio

I'd like to send an SMS to a Twilio SMS-enabled number via E-Mail, but can't find what domain I'd use for the E-Mail address.
(a) Is it possible to send E-Mail to Twilio SMS number?
(b) If so, what would the domain be?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Whilst it is the case that US carriers do have email addresses that forward messages as SMS messages to numbers, this is not possible with a Twilio number. In order to send an SMS message to a Twilio number, you need to send an SMS.